# trying to replace an element using sortable plugin on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list and I am using sortable jquery UI plugin to take advantage of drag and drop ability. One thing that I love about this plugin is that it is able to update the sorted list and return it, the follwoing is a simplified example of my code:

```
<ul id="sortable">
   <li class="ui-state-default" id="id1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-   arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" id="id2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" id="id3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
      <hr/>
   <li class="ui-state-default" id="id4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" id="id5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" id="id6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default" id="id7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

And my javascript code is:

```
 $( function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
 var idsInOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
                console.log("//-----------------^^^^");
                console.log(idsInOrder);
```

} );

Also here is the jsfiddle link :

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/zgq7a120/8/)

Now what I want to do: whenever a user clicked on the li with id2 I need to replace li with id2 after the line so the first element after black line will be li with id2. If I want to do it manually without sortable plugin I have to first remove li with id2 and the append it to the dom after hr. But it will not be as simple as this since sortable maintain the order of the lists and I am not sure if it is able to update it after this action. My question is if there is anyway that I can handle this with sortable plugin? if not what is the best way of approaching it?

Comment: There is no `<hr>` in the fiddle? I don't get what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ppasler I updated the code

Comment: Thanks, still I don't get the problem :)

Comment: @ppasler SO the problem is I do not know how to impelment the click scenario, if I click on for example li with id 2 it should be replaced under the line but at the same time the sortable list should update the order of the elements

Comment: @ppasler SO I am looking for the best way to implement that and if there is a way of doing it with the help of sortable plugin it will be awesome

Comment: @HamedMinaee sortable is designed for drag operations, not click. There is no built in method to perform this type of move. Plus, you now are dealing with the mousedown event to grab the sortable and then drag, and then mouseup, this would trigger click event too. May consider double click event, which this could be done in and update the sort order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, here is amethod using `dblclick` event.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/61mg55gx/

```
 $(function() {
   $("#sortable").sortable({
     items: "> li[id^='id']"
   });
   var idsInOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
   console.log("//-----------------^^^^");
   console.log(idsInOrder);
   $("#sortable li[id='id2']").dblclick(function(e) {
     console.log("ID 2 has been double clicked.");
     $("#sortable li[id='id4']").after($(this).detach());
     $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
   })
 });
```

I suspect you could try to do this with `click` too and I am just being overly cautious.